# Adding Column Flags when Replacing Data Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, replace, flags

I have a base data table on SQL Server 2012 that is  replaced every night with a new data set with identical columns. Once the data table is replaced, how do I flag a column whose row values have changed since the last data upload? The data type of the columns in questions are VARCHAR(255) and there can be multiple columns that require such a flag

The benefit I see in trying to implement the above solution is when I have to export data, I can reduce resource utilization by only pulling those rows that have a ISNOTNULL Column change flag

Thanks for your help!

Comment: sample data, code, and schema will make it easier to help you; just as a stab in the dark, sounds like a case for the rowversion datatype. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: @StuartAinsworth Exactly what I was looking for, just couldn't explain it in those terms. Thanks a ton for your help!